# Combining columns in DataTables, while keeping the column headers

Tags: datatables, html-table

In DataTables, is it possible to combine the values of two columns into one column, while keeping the two column headers and sorting options?

I would like to display names as `{Firstname} {Surname}` in one column, but still keep the possibility to sort by both `Firstname` and by `Surname`.

So the table should be rendered something like this:

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="sorting">Firstname</th>
      <th class="sorting">Surname</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">Donna Summer</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">Quincy Jones</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

When ordering by `Firstname`, Donna Summer would come before Quincy Jones, while when ordering by `Surname`, Quincy Jones would come before Donna Summer.

### Edit: Clarification

The original table is without the classes or colspans, and the firstnames and surnames are put in two different columns:

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>Surname</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Donna</td>
      <td>Summer</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Quincy</td>
      <td>Jones</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I'm looking for any options I can set when initializing the `DataTable` to render the two columns into a `colspan="2"`-column for the rows in `<tbody>` but not in `<thead>`.

Comment: How does the initiallization of your dataTable look like?

Comment: @davidkonrad See my edited post for info. I currently don't set any special options in the initialization of DataTable: $('table').DataTable();

Comment: Unfortunetaly dataTables does not support colspans, at all. You can have colspans if you are using multiple `<thead>` sections, but not in `<tbody>`. But you _can_ easily show the combined named and sort by surname only, for example.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the info :) Do you know if such functionality would be possible to add through a plugin?

Comment: I doubt it. Such plugin should override a lot of dataTables internal behaviour. But as mentioned, you could experment with multiple headers, hide the injected header and attach filter events to your own.